# How to add image file in json using phonegap?

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, camera

I have a problem saving an image in JSON. I can access the mobile camera using this code:

```
var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

// Wait for PhoneGap to connect with the device
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

// PhoneGap is ready to be used!
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

function onPhotoFileSuccess(imageData) {
  // Get image handle
  console.log(JSON.stringify(imageData));

  var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

  smallImage.style.display = 'block';

  smallImage.src = imageData;
  location.href = "#pageone";
}

function capturePhotoWithFile() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoFileSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI });
}

function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

My problem is that I have a form with text that should take and save a picture. This is my code that adds and saves the form without the image:

```js
function Add(){
  var client = JSON.stringify({
   repairNum : $("#repairNum").val(),
   fname    : $("#fname").val(),
   lname  : $("#lname").val(),
   address : $("#address").val(),
  });
   jewelryRepair.push(client);
   localStorage.setItem("jewelryRepair", JSON.stringify(jewelryRepair));
   alert("The data was saved.");
   return true;
 }
```

My question is, how can I insert the image file in this function add()? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it `imgData` that you want to store in `client`? If so what format in `imgData` in? Can you print the contents of `imgData`.

Comment: Hi! for reference, this is the link of my work. [link](https://github.com/emae0528/sampleCode.git)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Add()` gets called after `onPhotoFileSuccess()`, then you can do this in your `Add()` function (see below).  It will be a data url - meaning the url has all of the image data encoded within it.

```
function Add(){
        var client = JSON.stringify({
            repairNum : $("#repairNum").val(),
            fname    : $("#fname").val(),
            lname  : $("#lname").val(),
            address : $("#address").val(),
            photoData: $("#smallImage").attr("src")
        });
            jewelryRepair.push(client);
            localStorage.setItem("jewelryRepair", JSON.stringify(jewelryRepair));
            alert("The data was saved.");
            return true;
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Shawn Thanks for the answer, but when i tried, the image appears to be broken.

Comment: This is the repository of my work :) [Github Repo](https://github.com/emae0528/sampleCode.git)